# Function returning an object throws error

Tags: object, ms-access, vba, return-type

I have a function that should return an object of a class. The function looks like this:

```
Public Function GetPerson(personID As Integer) As clsPerson
    Dim sqlAdapter As New clsSQLAdapter
    Dim person As New clsPerson
    Dim recordset As recordset

    query = "SELECT ID, Anrede_ID, Nachname, Vorname FROM Person WHERE Person.ID = " & personID

    Set recordset = sqlAdapter.recordset(query)
    person.personID = recordset.Fields(0).Value
    If (recordset.Fields(1).Value = kAnrede.FRAU) Then
        Set person.anrede = kAnrede.FRAU
    ElseIf (recordset.Fields(1).Value = kAnrede.HERR) Then
        Set person.anrede = kAnrede.HERR
    End If
    person.nachName = recordset.Fields(2).Value
    person.vorName = recordset.Fields(3).Value
    Set GetPerson = person
End Function
```

But when I call the the function from another module, I get an error 91 at the line

```
person = sqlController.GetPerson(1)
```

stating: "Object variable or with block variable not set":

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Dim sqlController As New clsSQLController
    Dim person As New clsPerson

    person = sqlController.GetPerson(1)

End Sub
```

Also when I debug the programm, it tells me that the Type of *sqlController.GetPerson(1)* is Integer.
Is it even possible to do this, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I got the answer by myself. It is not that hard if you know it, I guess.

With `Public Function GetPerson(personID As Integer) As clsPerson` you seem to only declare the function type as clsPerson, but the function has no instance of `clsPerson`.
So you need to create an instance inside the function, like this:

```
Public Function GetPerson(personID As Integer) As clsPerson

    Set GetPerson = New clsPerson '<- This line is the important part

    'All the other code

    Set GetPerson = person
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add a `Set` statement to your event handler:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Dim sqlController As New clsSQLController
    Dim person As clsPerson

    Set person = sqlController.GetPerson(1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

'Return person' instead of 'Set GetPerson = person'

Comment: This is VBA, not VB.net. I found the answer myself, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477296/function-returning-an-object-throws-error/32479271#32479271).